# Play! Framework - Using MySQL and MongoDB for same application

Tags: mysql, mongodb, playframework, playframework-1.x, hibernate-annotations

Is it possible to user `MySQL Database` and `MongoDb` database for same project using Play! framework?

for example: 
I want

```
@Entity Person to interact with my MySQL database and  
@Entity PersonData to interact with my MongoDB database?
```

How can I do that?

Please let me know
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  Just use the Morphia plugin for Play.  I have done it before.  It is quite simple.

For the MongoDB models, just do something like this:

```
import play.modules.morphia.Model;

@Entity
public class YourMongoModel extends Model {
   ...
}
```

For the MySQL model, do this:

```
import play.db.jpa.Model;

@Entity
public class LogMessageX extends Model {
  ...
}
```

Notice the different imports.

Then the application.conf file should contains something like this:

```
# For MongoDB
morphia.db.host=localhost
morphia.db.port=27017
morphia.db.name=YourMongoDBName

# for MySQL
db=mysql:user:pwd@database_name
```

Comment: A special note about the @Entity annotation, the one you used to annotate JPA model class should be import as `javax.persistence` and the one for Morphia model should be `com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Entity`

Comment: What about Jongo ? can I use @MongoEntity with it ?

Answer (score 2):

On the MySQL entity extend Model and add the JPA annotation (@Entity).

For Mongo you need to use a third-party module such as this one:
http://www.playframework.org/modules/mongo-1.3/home

Example:

@MongoEntity("collectionName")

public class Car extends MongoModel {

```
public String name;
public String colour;
public int topSpeed;
```

}

Play's JPA plugin will not modify the Mongo class since it won't have the JPA @Entity annotation.

For anyone out there interested, checkout Play's JPAEnhancer. It uses javaassist to modify the bytecode and add all the method impls - very cool!